# Drupal change URL path settings will cause "page not found" issue

Tags: drupal, path, drupal-7

I create a content "testpage" and set the "url path settings" as "mysite/testpage" and I will see the page work well.
Then when I change the "url path settings" as "mysite/test", i cannot see this page and it will have the "page not found" error.
If I change the "url path settings" as none, still the "page not found" error.

This problem bothered me for a long time.
Waiting for your solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) to cover this issue.

Using redirect, you can issue a `moved permanently` HTTP code from "mysite/testpage" to "mysite/test"

Hope this helps... Muhammad.